# Find any of the list element present in given string

Tags: java, string

I have a list of strings say "abc" "bcd" "xyz" etc
and a string "xyzxxxxxxxxx" and i need to find whether any of the list value is present in the string.

in C# we have .any function to find it . Is there any way in java??

Comment: Thanks everyone for the reply i am looking for best way of doing this. i dont want to iterate the whole list every time

Comment: there is a fuction in java containsAll(collection) i need containsAny()

Comment: The `containsAll/containsAny` methods will loop over the list internally anyway. whether you spend your time looking for a method to do it for you or write it yourself, the result is the same: lists get iterated over =)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible in 1 line, but you can loop over the list and use `.contains()`

```
String[] listOfString = { "abc", "bcd", "xyz" };
String s = "xyzxxxxxxxxx";
for (String temp : listOfStrings) {
    s.contains(temp);
}
```

You can also use `indexOf()` if you want to know the position of the occurrence.

Answer (score 1):

You can look for a presence of a substring within a larger string by using the `String.contains` method:

```
String needle = "abc";
String haystack = "xyzxxxxxxxxx";
if (haystack.contains(needle)) {
   // react accordingly
}
```

To expand that to your specific requirement, you can simply loop over all of your substrings and check each of them in turn. (Possibly short-circuiting early depending on what you want to do in that case where a match is found).

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] strings = new String[]{"abc", "dfg"};
        String ss = "abcd";
        for(String s : strings) {
            System.out.println(ss + " contains " + s + ": " + ss.contains(s));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an example that would do what you are trying to achieve:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList("abc","bcd", "xyz");
    String search = "xyzxxxxxxxxx";
    for (String s : list) {
        if (search.contains(s)) {
            System.out.println("Found " + s + " in " + search);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like:

```
String source = "xyzxxxxxxxxx";
List<String> strings = ...;
for (int i = 0; i < string.size();i++)
{
    if (source.contains(strings.get(i))
    {
         System.out.println("Match found at " + (i + 1));
         break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through your list and use

C# `String.IndexOf`

Java `String.indexOf`

Answer (score 0):

you could iterate over the list, and call `string.contains(listelement)` everytime.